# Can't disable autoplay in javascript in an embedded Twitch element. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, embedding, twitch, autoplay

This is the code I'm running right now:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="DE">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
<meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
<meta name="author" content="xPlayzTV">

</head>

<body>
<!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
<div id="twitch-embed"></div>

<!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
<script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>

<!--
  Create a Twitch.Embed object that will render
  within the "twitch-embed" root element.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
    width: "480",
    height: "270",
theme: "dark",
    channel: "onyxtao",
    layout: "video",
    autoplay: "false",
muted: "true",
    // only needed if your site is also embedded on embed.example.com and othersite.example.com 
    parent: ["www.onyx-warframe.com"]
  });

  embed.addEventListener(Twitch.Embed.VIDEO_READY, () => {
    var player = embed.getPlayer();
    player.play();
  });
```

As you can see I have a line saying that `autoplay` is set to false. Despite being a listed `boolean` on Twitch's embedding guide, it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried replacing it with 0, and completely removing the `autoplay` row, but neither worked. Does anyone have other solutions to this, ideally with an explanation so I know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cast your variables as strings instead of booleans or integers leading to unexpected behaviour

```js
      var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: "480",
        height: "270",
        theme: "dark",
        channel: "onyxtao",
        layout: "video",
        autoplay: "false",
        muted: "true",
        // only needed if your site is also embedded on embed.example.com and othersite.example.com 
        parent: ["www.onyx-warframe.com"]
      });
```

Should be

```js
      var embed = new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: 480,
        height: 270,
        theme: "dark",
        channel: "onyxtao",
        layout: "video",
        autoplay: false,
        muted: true,
        parent: ["www.onyx-warframe.com"]
      });
```

So your "false" as treated as a "truthy"

Edit:

You also need to remove

```js
      embed.addEventListener(Twitch.Embed.VIDEO_READY, () => {
        var player = embed.getPlayer();
        player.play();
      });
```

As this will trigger the play function when the player has finished loading

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seemed logical, but I just edited the code and tested if it works, and I still run into the same issue. When I open my site, all players autoplay immediately, despite the edited code. Is there a different way to disable autoplay by any chance?

Comment: See the post edit, you need to remove the On Ready -> Play code